# Month by Month Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I have a list of dates and data that go back a year. In Excel, I made a pivot table that shows all these dates. In the columns label under data filters I see a lot of weekly, monthly, yearly information that is available, but the one I’m looking for is the one that will separate my dates by each month similar to the quarterly function.

Is this something I can do with the pivot table function, or would I need to do something else (and what would that be)?

Comment: I've excel 2010 and I've an option in date filters "all date periods" which contains month names too. If you don't have Excel 2010 then probably you need to add a column to your data for month and filter on that in pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a helper column to set the month in the format you want.  So when you place the month helper column in a pivot table it will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the format of your date to only "mmm" (month) format. Either by changing in your raw data or from your pivot table, under the "field settings" > "Number format" > custom and then type mmm.

If you want to avoid changing your raw data, you can try to add a column and copy and paste your dates and then change the format under "format cells", and then adopt that column in your pivot table.